# How can i check normality of some values in column with some confidence level in R

Tags: r

I'm not sure, if I understand good the issue of normality in R.

I have some exercise where i need to check if with confidence level of alpha=0.05 my values in column have normal distribution. Additionally i need to say if i reject hypothesis 0 or not and why.

normaly i will use just `t.test()` function and the returned `p.value` i will compare with alpha (if less then i accept H0, if not i'm rejecting h0), but i think it's not the point of exercise, I need to check if my columns are characterised by normal distribution

Can anybody help me with this statistics exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shapiro.test` to do this.

To check all columns at once and get the `p.values`:

```
sapply(mtcars, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value)

         mpg          cyl         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec           vs           am         gear         carb 
1.228814e-01 6.058338e-06 2.080657e-02 4.880824e-02 1.100608e-01 9.265499e-02 5.935176e-01 9.737376e-08 7.836354e-08 1.306844e-05 4.382405e-04
```